# #define SSL_CONNECTION_NO_CONST

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

The ssl_local.h openssl header file contains the following

```
#  define SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL(ssl) \
    SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_int(ssl, SSL_CONNECTION_NO_CONST)
    
# define SSL_CONNECTION_NO_CONST

# define SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_ONLY_int(ssl, c) \
    ((ssl) == NULL ? NULL                         \
     : ((ssl)->type == SSL_TYPE_SSL_CONNECTION    \
       ? (c SSL_CONNECTION *)(ssl)                \
       : NULL))
```

This macro is called by:

```
int SSL_connect(SSL *s)
{
    SSL_CONNECTION *sc = SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL(s);
```

I don't understand what the following macro does, because it has no actual definition.

```
# define SSL_CONNECTION_NO_CONST
```

Yet it is used in the following macro mentioned abbove.

```
SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_ONLY_int(ssl, c)
```

Comment: Based on the variable name `NO_CONST`, it appears to be a preprocessor trick to avoid constants.  I expect this to be a rather commonly used trick, so I tried quite a few different keywords in search of an explanation but couldn't find a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the macro is used as the second argument `c` to `SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_ONLY_int` and there used as a prefix for `SSL_CONNECTION`:

```
? (c SSL_CONNECTION *)(ssl)                \
  ^^^^
```

There are actually multiple uses of `SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_ONLY_int` in `ssl_local.h`:

```
#  define SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL(ssl) \
    SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_int(ssl, SSL_CONNECTION_NO_CONST)
#  define SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_CONST_SSL(ssl) \
    SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL_int(ssl, const)
```

Invoked with `SSL_CONNECTION_NO_CONST` in `SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL` this expands `c` to an empty string, i.e.

```
? ( SSL_CONNECTION *)(ssl)   
  ^^^^
```

Invoked with `const` in `SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_CONST_SSL` this expands `c` to an `const`, i.e.

```
? (const SSL_CONNECTION *)(ssl)   
  ^^^^^^^
```

Both `SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_SSL` and `SSL_CONNECTION_FROM_CONST_SSL` are used in multiple places inside the OpenSSL source code, so there seems to be use cases for both variants - with and without `const`.